# How to set a formula in an Excel cell using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, formula

Scott Craner gave me this solution to set a formula in one cell:

```
Range("F4").Formula = "=IF(D4,B4,"""")"
```

Now I want to apply that dynamically.  Here is my translation:

```
   For i = 4 to 10
       Range("F" & i).Formula = "=IF(D" & i ",B" & i ", """")"
   Next i
```

This turns red in the editor right away.  I need something that will run.  Tnx in advance.

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Two things: "It turns red" is not an error code, and please don't ask for 'good references' so your question doesn't get closed for being off topic (requesting an outside resource).

Comment: no loop: `Range("F4:F10").Formula = "=IF(D4,B4,"""")"`

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs "it turns red" is actually a plain old compile-time *syntax error*.

Comment: BTW: it will not compile as you are missing `&`: `"=IF(D" & i & ",B" & i & ", """")"` But the no loop needed option is quicker.

Comment: Yes  Scott Craner's Range("F" & i ).Formula = "=IF(D" & i & ",B" & i & ", """")" loops just fine.  Tnx.

Answer (score 1):

Like [Scott Craner said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118178/how-to-set-a-formula-in-an-excel-cell-using-vba#comment100754964_57118178), You don't need any loop for this.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F4:F10").Formula = "=IF(D4,B4,"""")"
```

That will do exactly what you're trying to achieve. Excel is that smart!

Comment: I don't know in advance what the range will be.  Hence the loop.

Comment: @Chas you have to know the extents of the loop, just use those in the range itself and avoid the loop.

Comment: @Chas then do `ActiveSheet.Range("F" & startRow & ":F" & endRow).Formula = "=IF(D" & startRow & ",B" & startRow & ","""")"` - no need for a loop.